# Getting textarea value from form

Tags: php, html, textarea

I'm having an error regarding on getting value from the form of the other page.

Here's the code snippet:

```
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "ID: <input type='text' name='id' value='$row[id]'><br/>";
    echo "Date: <input type='text' name='date' value='$row[date]'><br/>";
    echo "Event: <textarea type='text' name='event'><?php echo $row[event]; ?></textarea><br/>";
    echo "Note: <input type='text' name='note' value='$row[note]'><br/>";
}
?>
```

The form has 2 options, `edit` and `delete`.
Getting the textarea's value is working, but unfortunately, it also displays the php code.

For example:
**Textarea's value**: `Welcome`
**How it displays**: `<?php echo Welcome; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this...

```
echo "Event: <textarea type='text' name='event'>".$row['event']."</textarea><br/>";
```

Comment: works great. but, still having problem. it edits all entry in my database :/

Comment: @pingboo23 show us the code that inserts into the database for that problem

Comment: @GertB. Maybe I'll just post another question for this another problem of mine.

Comment: @pingboo23 maybe that would be better indeed

Comment: @GertB. already posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074164/edited-all-entries-in-database-php)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
echo "Event: <textarea type='text' name='event'><?php echo $row[event]; ?></textarea><br/>";
```

to

```
echo "Event: <textarea type='text' name='event'>".$row['event']."</textarea><br/>";
```

Comment: Hi. I'm getting this error: `Notice: Use of undefined constant event - assumed 'event'`

Comment: Are you using $row[event] or $row['event'] ?

Comment: @pingboo23 change `$row[event]` to  `$row['event']`

Comment: `$row['event']` works fine. It only shows without `''` in your code. but still thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you  use `<?php` and `?>` inside your echo string

your array key 'event' also needs to be within single qoutes

change

```
echo "Event: <textarea type='text' name='event'><?php echo $row[event]; ?></textarea><br/>";
```

into

```
echo "Event: <textarea type='text' name='event'> $row['event'] </textarea><br/>";
```