# Edited all entries in database [php]

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a problem in editing data in my database. I only want to edit one entry but after I clicked edit, it shows that all the data in my database were edited.

**eventlist.php**

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","chess");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from events");

//echo "<a href='dashboard.php'>Home</a><br>";
echo "<table border=1 id='hor-minimalist-a' width='100%'>";
echo "<tr align='center'><td><b>Date</b></td><td><b>Event</b></td><td><b>Special Note</b></td><td colspan='2'>Options</td></tr>";

$a=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  if($a%2==0){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#b2d5ff' width='100'>"."<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['event'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['note'] . "</td>"  
  . "</td><td><a href='editevent.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='deleteevent.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
}
else{
    echo "<tr>"."<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['event'] . "</td> <td>" . $row['note'] . "</td>"  
  . "</td><td><a href='editevent.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='deleteevent.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
}

$a++;


}
echo '</table>';
echo "<center><a href='addevent.php'><button type='submit' class='button'>Add New</button></a></center>";


?>
```

**editevent.php**

```
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "ID: <input type='text' name='id' value='$row[id]'><br/>";
    echo "Date: <input type='text' name='date' value='$row[date]'><br/>";
    echo "Event: <textarea type='text' name='event'>".$row['event']."</textarea><br/>";
    echo "Note: <input type='text' name='note' value='$row[note]'><br/>";
}
?>
```

**updateevent.php**

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$event = $_POST['event'];
$note = $_POST['note'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","chess");
mysqli_query($con,"update events set date='$date', event='$event', note='$note' where id = id");

header('location: eventlist.php');

?>
```

Comment: `where id = id` will test for database records where the id column in the database record is equal to the id column in the database record

Comment: `id` is the name of a column in your database.... `$id` is a PHP variable, not `id`

Comment: Learn to use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements and bind variables; and when you want to test a variable against a column name, don't test column name against column name. In your SQL statement, how do you expect the database to know that `id` isn't supposed to refer to the column name but to your `$id` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"update events set date='$date', event='$event', note='$note' where id = id"
```

`where id = id` is true for all rows, so all rows get updated. You probably ment to write `where id = $id`.

Also note that your query is open to SQL injection. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: I recommend him to use prepared statements

Comment: already used this codes in other php page. I just got this error when I changed my `input` to `<textarea>` for a reason.

Comment: @user4035: I added that to my answer.

Comment: works great. thankyou :) I'll just accept your answer later, can't accept for 5mins. @Arjan

Comment: @pingboo23: this has nothing to do with input or textarea tags.